# I have search about auto for but still here is coming segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++17

can anyone see my code why it is showing segmentation fault
input: 3 def de fgh

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> v[i];
    }
    for(auto x : v)
        cout << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line,

```
cin >> v[i];
```

you request a reference to the `i`th element in `v`, but the vector is empty.  You can change the part before the loop to

```
vector<string> v;
int n;
cin >> n;
v.resize(n); // <= this one is required.
```

to setup the vector such that it contains `n` default-constructed elements (in this case, zeros). Then it's valid to access `v[i]` within the correct bounds.

Comment: Thanks bro for telling I was upset for 2 days.